# How to sum amount having similar names in excel using python?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FL18.jpg)

I want to create a dataframe where the amount of similar heading has been added up?

Comment: The image for data is in the link

Comment: Please paste the data here, not the image.

Comment: I have given you the answer below but remember next time to give link to data file or put your over here, do not image of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use pandas module in python to aggregate the `Amount` grouped by `Type`.

***I have extracted your data from the image provided by you and then convert that into csv file.***

As you are aware of Dataframe in python, you might be aware of csv file.
If not go through this [url](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/pandas_csv.asp).

> I want to create a dataframe where the amount of similar heading has been added up?

`Use the code below`

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
# I named the data file as data.csv
data.groupby("Type").agg({"Amount": sum})
```

Here is your data provided by you in image

```
Amount,Type
19600,Wage
50000,Wage
1650,Misc
10100,Mess
3500,Wage
1000,Advance
14210,Mess
9240,Mess
1500,Plumbing
4500,Mess
21000,Mess
53000,Deposit
16300,Wage
50000,Constructi
21280,Wood
10000,Furniture
228000,Material
5000,Advance
7000,Misc
1500,Wage
5000,Advance
11000,Misc
50000,Wood
5000,Wage
1220,Mess
14500,Mess
2000,Mess
```

Here is the output after running the above code

```
            Amount
Type
Advance      11000
Constructi   50000
Deposit      53000
Furniture    10000
Material    228000
Mess         76770
Misc         19650
Plumbing      1500
Wage         95900
Wood         71280
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with pandas dataframes then you can:

```
dataframe_name.groupby("Type", as_index=False).sum()
```

P.S. **as_index=False** is optional here and you can omit it.